# enum as generic type in typescript

Tags: typescript, redux, enums

I would like to declare an interface with a member of type `enum`, as in - any `enum`. The idea here is to be a little safer than saying `any`, but still open to future `enum` types.

Use case:
I'm defining an action interface for redux, and I want the `BaseAction` interface to be something like this:

```
export interface BaseAction {
  type: enum;  //this gives an error
  payload: any;
}
```

**Is there a way to declare that the type of a member is `any` so long as it's an `enum`?**

This way, in the future, I may define this:

```
export enum SpecificActionType {
  SPECIFIC_1 = "SPECIFIC_ACTION_1",
  SPECIFIC_2 = "SPECIFIC_ACTION_2",
}

export interface SpecificAction1 extends BaseAction {
  type: SpecificActionType.SPECIFIC_1;
  payload: {
    id;
  };
}
```

As a disclaimer, I'm all new to redux and typescript, but looking for a good rigorous and future proof paradigm that's developer friendly. If you have a better idea, I'm open to that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically not a generic type, but a base type. Unfortunately typescript does not enable you to do such a thing. To provide this type of extensibility you need to either:

### Redefine the interface each time

```
export interface BaseAction {
  type: SpecificActionEnum | OtherActionEnum;  
  payload: any;
}
```

### Use the `any` or the `unknown` type.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a generic type but can't really enforce that it has to be an enum (AFAIK). But the repr of an enum at least has to be a string or a number.

So this is really more type *annotation* than any sort of compile-time type checking, but it may make the code more clear:

```
export interface BaseAction<T extends string | number> {
  type: T;
  payload: any;
}

export enum SpecificActionType {
  SPECIFIC_1 = "SPECIFIC_ACTION_1",
  SPECIFIC_2 = "SPECIFIC_ACTION_2",
}

export interface SpecificAction1 extends BaseAction<SpecificActionType> {
  type: SpecificActionType.SPECIFIC_1;
  payload: {
    id: number;
  };
}
```

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgIUwGdgBBbGBCJAHgBU5RUkATIuImKZAczgB84SAK4BbAEZoAfHADeAKDhwYATzDAAXHDoBuRXDCYVAGwiYWWzEhV6AvvPmhIsRiNFwAyuuwJ0CbOSU1HRqeApKHgAKAKIAwgCSAGLxsQD6AIxwALxwAERRcUkpqaSxdPEA8gByGbkANPoFCclpAEzZeU1FaaXl1amt9fL2juDQ8MioGDh4XsA+fgEUVEiZTMCs7IQkgSs0cwv+u8GhMuHKoVoHvkfLJ+oAdF0tGXpKhiZmFnL6SgjfbkkUDecFsdiAA)